# filterBy not working for AngularJS for arrays inside objects

Tags: angularjs

```
I have the following code:
```

I am trying to filter all the columns at the same time using one criteria.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="keyLegalEntity in keyLegalEntities | filterBy: ['gsCode','name','primaryContacts.kerberos','secondaryContacts.kerberos','additionalAttributes.cftcSwapDealer']:searchLE">
 <td style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" data-checklist-model="selectedkeyLegalEntities.keyLegalEntities" checklist-change="LEUpdate()" data-checklist-value="keyLegalEntity" checklist-comparator="compareFn" ng-disabled="!hasWriteEntitlement"></td>
 <td style="text-align: center">{{keyLegalEntity.gsCode}}</td>
 <td style="text-align: center">{{keyLegalEntity.name}}</td>
 <td style="text-align: center">{{formatPrimaryKerbs(keyLegalEntity)}}</td>
 <td style="text-align: center">{{formatSecondaryKerbs(keyLegalEntity)}}</td>
 <td style="text-align: center">{{keyLegalEntity.additionalAttributes.cftcSwapDealer}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

This is the data in one of the objects, i am able to filter on gs.code and name but not on all the other fields

[image]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/15QRT.png
```

Comment: Can you see the image with the backend data?

Comment: Is filterBy a custom filter you are using?? Can you please share that filter

Comment: Its a angular Library https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby